# How is this USB connector supposed to be soldered

Tags: connector, soldering, surface-mount, usb-c, solder-paste

I'm using this USB-C connector in a project but could not figure out how it should be soldered to the PCB. I could not figure it out from the datasheet either. It says it is an SMT component - does that imply that the through-hole legs can be soldered by adding solder paste on the area that is indicated in the datasheet? Should I add solder paste on the bottom side of the PCB as well in that case? Can this type of component be wave-soldered or does it require a selective wave-soldering process?

[USB4515-GF-A](https://gct.co/connector/usb4515)

[image]

Comment: Search for the terms "paste-in-hole" or "pin-in-paste" to see standard ways of dealing with this.

Comment: Sometimes i add extra copper pads with paste to the 4 outer holes. This way, reliability is increased.